# Why there is a different relative to Geodetic Azimuth from Arc Map from the original datums and transformations?

Tags: datum, direction, azimuth, geodetic

We where conducting a displacement for some **BM** *(**Old vs New values**)*, we made calculations on different platforms for the *North, East, Elevations*. We used the **NGS NCAT, Inverse 3D, TBC and manual calculations**. On these methods the variations are within minutes for the azimuths. But when using the *ArcMap - Toolbox - **Point Distance*** to calculate, the  differences of point to point are ok (Same on all platforms), on the contrary in the azimuth its when I see a big different up to 9°. (In azimuth from Plane (Grid) are same for all platforms.

Someone have a clue for this. 
Either on grid or geographic coords.

I found it interesting and curious.

Answer (score 1):

The azimuth at a point for a direction is unambiguously defined.

This cannot be said of the direction taken by the line connecting two points.

Is this line the shortest on a sphere, on an ellipsoid, on a plane, in a three-dimensional Euclidean space?

All of these lines start in a different direction, therefore they have a different azimuth at the point of origin.